# android class calling orientation from another class

Tags: android, class

I want to call my screen orientation from one activity to another to compress the code and also make it easier to call other functions.

```
public class Activity2 extends Activity{    
  public void Orientation(){
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
  }
}
```

The main application will call the orientation from another class:

```
public class main extends Activity {
  final Activity2 summon = new Activity2();
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    summon.Orientation();
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
  }
}
```

Can this be done? Sorry for my bad English, this is my second language.

Comment: why you want to do that? You must not create and `Activity` object by yourself. Leave this to android platform.

Comment: I made an application that need to be navigated i want a code that can be used so that all of the xml will have a orientation lock of landscape and the main will have an orientation lock of portrait

Answer (score 0):

in `onCreate()` of your activities, do this for setting `Landscape Orientation`

`this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);`

and this for `Portrait Orientation`

`this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);'

and let `Android` manage your activities and use `startActivity()` method to start another `Activity` from one `Activity`. Every activity will have its orientation as per its configuration.

regards,
Aqif Hamid

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can not create Activity object like that.

To answer your question(if i understood it correctly), you can set the oriantation of an activity in the manifest like this

```
 <activity
        android:name=".MyLandscapeActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        >
</activity>
```